# Как сделать деплой приложения на next.js и залить на свой сервер?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Не понимаю как разворачивать приложение на своем сервере. Сначала сделал npm run dev, после npm run build. Появилась папка out и ее содержимое закинул на сервер. Приложение не отрабатывает и выдает пустой экран. Я так понимаю это я делаю статичную сборку, а приложение динамически меняет контент и следовательно я делаю неправильно. В ноде я такой себе. Скажите, пожалуйста, какие шаги мне предпринять чтобы все заработало?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В итоге разобрался сам. Напишу ход действий, может кому пригодится.

1. Подключаемся через консоль к серверу и устанавливаем node.js если он не установлен
2. Переходим в папку где будет храниться проект и устанавливаем соединение с git репозиторием с Вашим проектом и клонируем проект (Или используйте fileZilla) (Само собой клонируем без папок .next и node_modules)
3. Заходим на сервер в папку проекта и устанавливаем зависимости npm install, так же через консоль.
4. Потом делаем npm run build (если будет ругаться, то попробуйте сначала npm run dev, потом build)
5. Запускам сервер npm run start (В идеале иметь самописный скрипт по запуску серва с использованием exporess чтобы настраивать порты и прочее, но так тоже запустится)
6. Если все правильно сделали, проект запустится под вашим хостом и портом.  172.11.1.111:3000  - пример.
   Надеюсь помог

Comment: nginx и прочее если нужно настраивать, то это уже бэк пусть помогает)